# The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported. (Microsoft SQL Server 2019)

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019-express

The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported. (Microsoft SQL Server)

[image]

Could anyone help with this ?

Comment: When does this error occur? When you start Mgmt Studio? When you're doing something in it?

Comment: create a new table

Comment: @marc_s  create a new table with menu

Comment: who can help, please

Comment: Did you specify any specific / custom collation when trying to create that table?

Comment: @marc_s , no specified anything